# Python/Kivy : Move cursor using keyboard up and down key into dynamic add row

Tags: python, python-2.7, kivy-language

I am using `python-2.7` and kivy. When i click on `+Add More` then row will be add dynamic.Someone help me that how to jump cursor `one row` to `another row` using keyboard?
If cursor into `2nd row`, `2nd column`.If i press `up` key then cursor should be jump into `1st row`, `2nd column`.And
If i press `down` key then cursor should be jump into `3rd row`, `2nd column`.

## test.py

```
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.properties import StringProperty

Window.size = (450, 325)


class display(Screen):

    def add_more(self):
        self.ids.rows.add_row()


class Row(BoxLayout):
    button_text = StringProperty("")


class Rows(BoxLayout):
    orientation = "vertical"
    row_count = 0

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Rows, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.add_row()

    def add_row(self):
        self.row_count += 1
        self.add_widget(Row(button_text=str(self.row_count)))


class test(App):

    def build(self):
        return self.root

if __name__ == '__main__':
    test().run()
```

## test.kv

```
<Row>:
    orientation: "horizontal"

    Button:
        text: root.button_text
        size_hint_x: .2

    TextInput:
        size_hint_x: .8

    TextInput:
        size_hint_x: .8


display:

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"

        BoxLayout:
            orientation: "horizontal"

            Button:
                size_hint_x: .2
                text: "+Add More"
                valign: 'bottom'
                on_press: root.add_more()


        BoxLayout:
            orientation: "horizontal"

        Rows:
            id: rows
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is as follow.Please refer to the snippets, example for details

## Snippets

## Please modify this function:

```
class display(Screen):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(display, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        Window.bind(on_key_down=self._on_keyboard_down)

    def _on_keyboard_down(self, instance, keyboard, keycode, text, modifiers):
        if int(keycode) == 81 or int(keycode) == 82:
            if int(keycode) == 82:
                key = 'up'
            if int(keycode) == 81:
                key = 'down'

            rows = self.ids.rows
            countRowLen = len(rows.children)
            i = 0
            for row in reversed(rows.children):
                i = i + 1
                j = 0
                for ch in reversed(row.children):
                    if isinstance(ch, TextInput):
                        j = j + 1
                        if ch.focus == True:
                            self.params = {'count': countRowLen, 'row':i, 'column':j, 'key':key, 'gridObj': rows}
                            set_focus_grid_use_keyboard(self)
                            return True
            return True

    def add_more(self):
        self.ids.rows.add_row()
```

## Add new function

```
def set_focus_grid_use_keyboard(obj):
    if int(obj.params['count']) == int(obj.params['row']) and obj.params['key'] == 'down':
        focusRow = int(1)
    elif int(obj.params['row']) == 1 and obj.params['key'] == 'up':
        focusRow = int(obj.params['count'])
    elif obj.params['key'] == 'down':
        focusRow =  int(obj.params['row']) + 1
    elif obj.params['key'] == 'up':
        focusRow =  int(obj.params['row']) - 1


    i = 0
    for row in reversed(obj.params['gridObj'].children):
        i += 1
        j = 0
        print(i)
        print(focusRow)
        if i == int(focusRow):
            for ch in reversed(row.children):
                if isinstance(ch, TextInput):
                    j += 1
                    if j == int(obj.params['column']):
                        ch.focus = True
                        return False
```

## Example

## test.py

```
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.properties import StringProperty
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput

Window.size = (450, 325)


def set_focus_grid_use_keyboard(obj):
    if int(obj.params['count']) == int(obj.params['row']) and obj.params['key'] == 'down':
        focusRow = int(1)
    elif int(obj.params['row']) == 1 and obj.params['key'] == 'up':
        focusRow = int(obj.params['count'])
    elif obj.params['key'] == 'down':
        focusRow =  int(obj.params['row']) + 1
    elif obj.params['key'] == 'up':
        focusRow =  int(obj.params['row']) - 1


    i = 0
    for row in reversed(obj.params['gridObj'].children):
        i += 1
        j = 0
        print(i)
        print(focusRow)
        if i == int(focusRow):
            for ch in reversed(row.children):
                if isinstance(ch, TextInput):
                    j += 1
                    if j == int(obj.params['column']):
                        ch.focus = True
                        return False


class display(Screen):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(display, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        Window.bind(on_key_down=self._on_keyboard_down)

    def _on_keyboard_down(self, instance, keyboard, keycode, text, modifiers):
        if int(keycode) == 81 or int(keycode) == 82:
            if int(keycode) == 82:
                key = 'up'
            if int(keycode) == 81:
                key = 'down'

            rows = self.ids.rows
            countRowLen = len(rows.children)
            i = 0
            for row in reversed(rows.children):
                i = i + 1
                j = 0
                for ch in reversed(row.children):
                    if isinstance(ch, TextInput):
                        j = j + 1
                        if ch.focus == True:
                            self.params = {'count': countRowLen, 'row':i, 'column':j, 'key':key, 'gridObj': rows}
                            set_focus_grid_use_keyboard(self)
                            return True
            return True

    def add_more(self):
        self.ids.rows.add_row()


class Row(BoxLayout):
    button_text = StringProperty("")


class Rows(BoxLayout):
    orientation = "vertical"
    row_count = 0

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Rows, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.add_row()

    def add_row(self):
        self.row_count += 1
        self.add_widget(Row(button_text=str(self.row_count)))


class test(App):

    def build(self):
        return self.root

if __name__ == '__main__':
    test().run()
```

## test.kv

```
<Row>:
    orientation: "horizontal"

    Button:
        text: root.button_text
        size_hint_x: .2

    TextInput:
        size_hint_x: .8

    TextInput:
        size_hint_x: .8


display:

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"

        BoxLayout:
            orientation: "horizontal"

            Button:
                size_hint_x: .2
                text: "+Add More"
                valign: 'bottom'
                on_press: root.add_more()


        BoxLayout:
            orientation: "horizontal"

        Rows:
            id: rows
```